# Passing through array that is in an object into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass an object into a function as a parameter, and assign things to properties of that object, then those would be accessible outside of the function. But I am not to clear on how it is done.

At first I thought it could be done using callbacks, but it was made clear to me that JavaScript does not work that way. I eventually managed to get it working, and the undefined error messages went way. But I wanted to now pass an array through the function. How can this be done? This is what I've done so far, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var journey = {};
journey['waypointsArrayItem'] = new Array();
setupAddress(journey)

function setupAddress(journey) {
    var waypointsItem = $('.timeline-item.active-item > .timeline-status > .waypoints').text().substring(4);
    journey.waypointsArrayItem = [];
    journey.waypointsArrayItem = listToArray(waypointsItem, ', ');
    for (var i = 0; i < waypointsArray.length; i++) {
        journey.waypointsArrayItem[i] = journey.waypointsArrayItem[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: So after calling the `setupAddress(journey)` function have you actually checked the `journey.waypointsArrayItem` array? Normally it should contain the expected items unless of course your jQuery selector `$('.timeline-item.active-item > .timeline-status > .waypoints').text().substring(4);` hasn't returned anything or it has crashed. In all cases you might consider consulting the console output in your browser for potential errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying array items to themselves. Copy from the `waypointsArray` array to the `journey.waypointsArrayItem` array:

```
function setupAddress(journey) {
  var waypointsItem = $('.timeline-item.active-item > .timeline-status > .waypoints').text().substring(4);
  var waypointsArray = listToArray(waypointsItem, ', ');
  for (var i = 0; i < waypointsArray.length; i++) {
    journey.waypointsArrayItem[i] = waypointsArray[i];
  }
}
```

Depending on what you need, you could also just replace the entire array:

```
function setupAddress(journey) {
  var waypointsItem = $('.timeline-item.active-item > .timeline-status > .waypoints').text().substring(4);
  journey.waypointsArrayItem = listToArray(waypointsItem, ', ')
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the following http://pastebin.com/6zMr2ZZs, but keep getting the following error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` at `journey.waypointsArrayItem[i] = waypointsArray[i] + ", Windy City";`. Any idea what could be causing it? My code looks fine. I must be missing something obvious *covers face*

Comment: @methuselah: There is some code missing there, from the middle of the array declaration to the function declaration. I mocked the data and the `listToArray` function, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/8uqr88ec/

Answer (score 1):

Assigning properties to an object in a function is the same as assigning properties outside of a function.

```
function addName(obj, name) {
  obj.name = name;
}

var bob = {};
console.log(bob.name); // undefined
addName(bob, 'Bob');
console.log(bob.name); // 'Bob'
```